# How to default the source folder for new JUnit tests in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, usability

Most of our Eclipse projects have multiple source folders, for example:

- src/main/java
- src/test/java

When you right-click on a class and choose New JUnit Test, the default source folder for the new test is "src/main/java" (presumably the first source folder listed in the project properties).

Is there any way to change the default source folder for new JUnit tests, so that when I do the above action, the new test will be created in say the "src/test/java" folder by default?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I use [moreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/), an Eclipse plugin to assist writing unit tests. Among other features, it lets you configure the default source folder of tests.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Unless you change the plugin code, the default source folder is always the same as that containing the class you right clicked on (not necessarily the first source folder listed).  I agree, it would be nice to be able to change it!

Comment: Dave - Have you tried my plug-in? It does exactly that : http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use my fast code eclipse plug-in. With this plug-in you can configure the test path to be `src/test/java` only once. It also has a jump to the unit test feature. It is available at : http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/.