# How do you change the default test location in Eclipse when using Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

If I'm looking at a class (MyComponent, say) somewhere underneath src/main/java in Eclipse, I can right click it and pick new...--> other --> JUnit test. Eclipse is smart enough to guess the name for the unit test class (MyComponentTest), but it insists on putting the unit test under src/main/java. Is there anything in Eclipse or m2Eclipse that can be set so that the default test location is src/test/java? Given that's the standard way of working with Maven, there has to be a setting for this somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: Good question! I'd like Eclipse to be smarter for this too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to default the source folder for new JUnit tests in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69063/how-to-default-the-source-folder-for-new-junit-tests-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, this bothers me too. I googled it and found this suggestion: [How to default the source folder for new JUnit tests in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69063/how-to-default-the-source-folder-for-new-junit-tests-in-eclipse).

Basically it says: I use moreUnit, an Eclipse plugin to assist writing unit tests. Among other features, it lets you configure the default source folder of tests.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a junit test, you can select another source folder than 'src/main/java'

Comment: Yes, you can. My point is I'd like the default to follow the Maven convention, rather than having to select another source folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you click 'new > junit test' while having an other source-folder selected, it will use that one as the target.

so i guess there is no 'default' it just uses the 'current' folder. sensible defaults is not what eclipse is good at.

what is eclipse good at at all?