# Eclipse: How to configure a default unit test directory

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, default, directory

I have two source folders, `src` and `test`. The *Quick JUnit* plugin allows me to "Open Testing Pair" quickly. If there is no testing pair, it opens the default JUnit Test Wizard, but the default directory is always `src` and and not `test`. Is there a way to configure a default unit test directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to default the source folder for new JUnit tests in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69063/how-to-default-the-source-folder-for-new-junit-tests-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is already answered, sorry!

[How to default the source folder for new JUnit tests in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69063/how-to-default-the-source-folder-for-new-junit-tests-in-eclipse)

MoreUnit works fine.